# How to make a POST to a route from collection_select in helper Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, onchange, collection-select

I'm a newbie in Ruby on Rails.
This is the helper method that I call from the html.

```
def select_user_role (user)
    @user = user
    collection_select(:user, :role, User.roles.to_a, :first, :first, {}, {
        data: {user_id: @user.id},
        onChange: ""
    })
end
```

The select works properly.

I would like to send a call to a route with some parameters in POST (like user id and role position) from the onChange. How am I supposed to do that?

The roles are defined as a enum in the User model.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `change` event listener to your `collection_select`, and this way, whenever the user changes makes a change in the selection, then you can make your request to the method you need in the controller you need.

Give an id to your `collection_select`, and add the `data` attribute `data-user` (as example):

```
  <%= collection_select(
      :user, 
      :role_id, 
      User.roles, 
      :first, 
      :first,
      {},
      {'data-user': 1}
    ) %> # Skipping the "on-tag" onChange attribute
```

Then you can create an script to get the rendered select tag, add the `change` event listener, get the `role` and `user` values, and make an XMLHttpRequest, passing those values as JSON, in a POST request:

```
  <script>
    let role_select = document.getElementById('user_role_id')
    role_select.addEventListener('change', function() {
      let role = this.value,
          user = this.dataset.user,
          xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

      xhr.open('POST', '/test', true)
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status == 200) {
          // Do whatever you want if it succeeds
        } else {
          // Do whatever you want if it doesn't succeed
        }
      }
      xhr.send(JSON.stringify({role_id: role, user_id: user}))
    })
  </script>
```

Comment: Where shoud I put the script?

Comment: You can try in the view, where the `collection_select` is rendered.

Comment: But can I do the same putting the collection in a helper?
Because I have not a form, it's just the select.

Comment: The helper will be used in a view? then it'll render the element as an html tag, if it's in the DOM then it'll be available for your script.